# dplyr filter keep the NAs AND OR conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, na

I have the following data with 10 entries:

```
test_data_1 <- structure(list(Art = c(188, NA, NA, 140, NA, 182, NA, NA, 182, 
                       NA)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                       ))
```

Let's say I want to keep only the NAs, 188 and 140. So I tried the following command:

```
test_data_1 %>% filter(is.na(Art), Art != 182) # with | instead of a comma, it works
```

With this command, a tibble with zero entries results. Why do I have to use the | sign instead of a comma? This site (https://sebastiansauer.github.io/dplyr_filter/) states: "Multiple logical comparisons can be combined. Just add ‘em up using commas; that amounts to logical OR “addition”:" So the comma should act as an OR, but it doesn't.
Another approach:

```
test_data_1 %>% filter(Art != 182)
```

Here, by dplyr default, the 6 NAs entries are deleted, which is not my wish. The command na.rm=FALSE doesn't help, either. Now zero entries are kept. Why is that? Why aren't at least the entries 188 and 140 kept?

```
test_data_1 %>% filter(Art != 182, na.rm=FALSE)
```

Last question: If I want to keep various numbers in a column, I could use %in% followed by a vector, e.g.:

```
test_data_1 %>% filter(Art %in% c(140,188))
```

But how could I combine %in% with is.na if I would just like to keep the NAs and e.g. 140?

Comment: You've basically answered your own question. The page you linked to is wrong. As the [dplyr documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html) says, `filter()` combines its arguments with `&`. If you want to use or instead, you have to use the `|` operator. There is no `na.rm` argument for `dplyr::filter()`.

Comment: Thanks Joe Roe! So both the comma and the & sign means AND. Are they always 100% interchangeable? I wonder why the dplyr documentations just talks about the & and not the comma in the arguments section. What is strange is that in the Examples, they say they will use the & but then in the command use the comma:
# When multiple expressions are used, they are combined using &
filter(starwars, hair_color == "none", eye_color == "black")

Comment: @SCW16 It is the `...` which implies variadic arguments, i.e. one or more, which we pass with `,` for more than one.. The documentation says `... - Expressions that return a logical value, and are defined in terms of the variables in .data. If multiple expressions are included, they are combined with the & operator. Only rows for which all conditions evaluate to TRUE are kept.`

Comment: I can see why it's confusing. `,` doesn't mean 'and' and it doesn't behave like this in other contexts. It's simply the syntax we use to separate arguments to a function. But filter (and several other tidyverse functions) have the convention that multiple conditions given as arguments are joined with a logical and. That is what the examples try to explain: filter(x = 1, y = 2) is *converted* to filter(x = 1 & y = 2). They're equivalent and you can write it the second way if you find that clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `|` instead of `&`.  With `filter`, multiple expressions separated by `,` are taken as `&`.  It is not possible to have a value that is both `NA` and not equal to 182

```
library(dplyr)
test_data_1 %>% 
   filter(is.na(Art) | Art != 182)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 1
    Art
  <dbl>
1   188
2    NA
3    NA
4   140
5    NA
6    NA
7    NA
8    NA
```

The second part of the question is with `%in%`.  We can use `|` again

```
test_data_1 %>%
   filter(Art %in% c(140,188) | is.na(Art))
# A tibble: 8 × 1
    Art
  <dbl>
1   188
2    NA
3    NA
4   140
5    NA
6    NA
7    NA
8    NA
```

NOTE: By default, `filter` removes the `NA` elements.  In addition, there is no `na.rm` argument in `filter`

Comment: Thanks akrun! For the na.rm argument, I was confused because ?filter gave starwars %>% filter(mass > mean(mass, na.rm = TRUE)) as an example. But here, this argument was for the mean function.
For the second part of my question with %in%: I meant if it was possible to include the is.na part within the %in% part. So I guess there is no way to do that?

Comment: @SCW16 1) `mean`, `sum`, `min`, `max`, `range`... all have `na.rm` argument.  One way to check is the usage in the documentation of function with `?filter` or `help("filter")`.   2) `%in%` by default returns `FALSE` for `NA` elements  whereas `==` returns `NA`.  You may create a new function on top of `%in%` that checks the `NA` to return as `TRUE`